# How to access family belonging of R package function

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying on creating my first R package. Google'd but nothing specific to my question came up.

In the roxygen manual it says

> **@family family name Automatically adds see-also cross-references between all functions in a family. A function can belong to multiple
>   families.**

How do I access my functions family beloning? In the documentation after adding my `@family text` nothing shows up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Hadley's book, `@family` should be plural.

> If you have a family of related functions where every function should link to every other function in the family, use @family. The value of @family should be plural.

Instead of `@family text` you might need to show `@family some text` for example.

Also, the same `@family` tag should be added to multiple functions.  For example, in the `devtools` package a couple of functions `?devtools::dev-example` and `?devtools::run-examples` have the tag

```
#' @family example functions
```

The **See Also** section has links to each other